# Adding a second graph to a legend

Tags: r, statistics

I am creating a plot like that:

```
plot(sale, x = timeSeq, type = "o", xlim = timeLine, ylim = c(-.1, .4))
lines(purchase, x = timeSeq, type = "o", col="red", pch=0)
axis(side = 1, at = timeSeq)
abline(v = 0, col = "black")
legend("topright", "sale" ,pch = 1 )
```

As you can see I want to add a legend to my plot, however I currently can only add the sale to my plot.

[image]

I want to add a legend so that the red line is purchase and the blackline is sale in the legend?

Any suggestions how to add this?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
legend("topright", c("sale", "purchase") ,pch = c(1,0), col=c("black", "red") )
```

Comment: btw how to make the legend small so that it does not scale when I scale the plot in RStudio?